# Bare metal programming with CMSIS library

Tags: makefile, stm32, bare-metal, nucleo, cmsis

I want to build a simple project by programming nucleo f103rb board (just blink led for the moment). I want to use CMSIS library to run my code. ( yes I know there is platform io and Kiel IDEs that integrate CMSIS, ). I want to build it for zero using a Juste visual studio code, cmsis library and a makefile. Where I could find cmsis library for nucleo f103rb board and how to generate a makefile for it?

I tried to find a cmsis library but I didn't find it, the same thing for a makefile examples

Comment: If you type CMSIS in google you will just get the CMSIS core from ARM.  For the device specific part, including project examples, you need to search for STM32F0Cube.

Comment: I got CMSIS [here](https://github.com/modm-io/cmsis-header-stm32). And [here](https://github.com/eddyem/stm32samples) you can find some my projects: for STM32F0, F103, F303 and very little for F407.